# Как узнать когда View отрисовалась?

Tags: android

В начале программы мне нужно узнать Y позицию View элемента. Как мне узнать, когда она отрисовалась? Если я буду брать view.`getY()` позицию в конце метода `onCreate`, тозначение будет 0, т.к. видимо оно еще не успело отрисоваться. Пробовал по кнопке брать позицию, берет, все хорошо. Но нужно сделать чтобы брало значение само в начале входа в активити.

Comment: Попробуйте послать broadcast в onCreate, а в нём обработать то что надо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Повесить обработчик на вьюху, который сработает, когда она отрисуется.

```
final View v = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_view);
ViewTreeObserver vto = v.getViewTreeObserver();  
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {  
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override  
    public void onGlobalLayout() {  
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) 
        v.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this); 
    else
        v.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

    // здесь можно получить view.getY()

     }  
});
```